# Ubuntu Touch - change ebay from US locale to UK

Tags: ubuntu-touch, locale, nexus-4

I am trying Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 4 and when using ebay, it assumes that I am in the US and not the UK.  I have tried searching for a locale setting, but to no avail.  Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the browser? As if so you can just type ebay.co.uk rather than ebay or ebay.com.